# Mustek 1200 UB Plus on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, drivers, scanner

I have a Mustek 1200 UB Plus scanner. Is it possible to install this on Windows 7? There are no drivers for it for 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a spare license for some 32-bit version of Windows, you can try putting it on a virtual machine and forwarding the scanner to it, I've been doing it successfully. Linux may work too if it has appropriate drivers, it's worth giving it a try as you don't have to pay for it.

Comment: This is a common use case for XP Mode which includes a fully licensed copy of Windows XP Professional 32bit. It is included as an optional download for Windows 7 Professional and higher editions.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no 64-bit drivers offered by Mustek then you are out of luck, it's not possible to use a 32-bit driver, on a 64-bit operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I know how you can trick Win 7 x86 to install XP drivers for your scanner, but I don't think that you can make your scanner to work under Win 7 x64. The option that I have had a chance to try is [Hamrick Software's Vuescan](http://www.hamrick.com/) and it works with your scanner. But this is not a free solution :(